# How to o get the Rssi value for a given packet

Tags: rssi, tinyos

How to get the Rssi value for a given packet by using the `CC2420Packet.getRssi()` method or any method on tinyos 2.0.

I used `CC2420Packet.getRssi()` but I got this error:

```
interface CC2420Packet not found
```

Comment: What platform do you use? CC2420Packet is a chip-specific interface provided by the CC2420 radio chip. Methods for obtaining RSSI will be chip-specific as well.

Comment: yes i work with CC2420 radio chip but in the compilation i get always erreur of interface CC2420Packet not found

Comment: Then, what platform do you use? TinyOS looks for source files in directories defined in a file tos/platforms/{platform-name}/.platform. `CC2420Packet` interface definition is in the directory tos/chips/cc2420/interfaces/. This entry should be in the .platform file. However, I think that lack of this entry would prevent from compilation of any code that uses radio, so you probably have another bug. Maybe you missed `uses interface CC2420Packet;` in the preamble? Post your code - it would be easier to help.